# Exclude empty Category Names in foreach($categories as $category)

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I echo a list of categories with the following lines of code. Unfortunatley the `foreach($categories as $category) {...` part lists also categories with no posts in it. Any idea how to exclude the empty categories by using the same structure?

```
<?php $categories = get_categories('exclude=' . implode(',', test_blog_cats()) . ', 1'); ?>

<?php if (!isset($_GET['category'])) {  
    echo '<li><a class="popular-categories icon-caret-left" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . __('All Categories', 'test') . '</a></li>';                              
} else {
    echo '<li><a class="popular-categories" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . __('All Categories', 'test') . '</a></li>';                                                           
?>

<?php foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li>
        <a class="popular-categories<?php if (isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] == $category->category_nicename) echo ' icon-caret-left bodycolor'; ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?category=<?php echo $category->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?>&nbsp;</a> 
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine for me...

```html
<?php
// Check ALL categories for posts of given post type
$categories = get_categories();

// the below will only list categories with one or more post
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
}
?>
```